# Update UI Programmatically on Orientation Change

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to update the UI contents when user changes the orientation of the device. 
I create one UITableView at -viewDidLoad event with the following code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)    name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];

    self.tv = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    self.tv.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.tv.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    self.tv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    self.tv.delegate = self;
    self.tv.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tv];

}
```

I handle the orientation changes with the following events but i cannot scale tableview to screen. 
Could you please help me to find out what i'm missing?

```
#pragma mark - orientation events

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
    [self adjustViewsForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
}

-(void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {


    [self.tv reloadData];
    if( orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){

    }
    if( orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

    }
}
```

Comment: The `autoresizingMask` should just be `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`.

Comment: I change autoresizingmask property of tableview to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight but it didn't work. Should i change the autoresizingmask property of self.view?

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't see that. Don't set the `autoresizingMask` of `self.view`. It will be set properly for you.

Comment: Well, i removed that line but when i change the orientation of the simulator to landscape, tableview only uses the half of screen.